# A word for an examination of a product's design

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word describes a kind of review of a product that closely examines its design. In my case specifically a video examining the design of a level in a game.

> I regularly watch _____ of video games on YouTube to give me ideas for my game's design.

I think the word I am thinking of ends in *"-spective*", like the words *retrospective* and *introspective*, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: I'm not convinced you'll find a single word; would *design **analysis*** work? Unless you're thinking of a design *perspective*.

Comment: I don't see how you could learn much about the *design* of a game from a YouTube video.  At best you'd be learning about the *user interface* or *game externals*.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Of course, analysis was what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @HotLicks For example [Mark Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqJ-Xo29CKyLTjn6z2XwYAw)'s videos

Answer (score -1):

The word the OP was looking for was apparently **analysis**

> #### Analysis
>
> əˈnalɪsɪs/
>   **noun**
>   1. detailed examination of the elements or structure of something.
>   "*statistical analysis*"

This could then form the compound noun *design analysis* or just be used by itself.

This would work in the following sentence:

> I regularly watch *design analyses* of video games on YouTube to give me ideas for my game's design.

But this sentence seems more natural.

> I regularly watch videos *analysing the design* of video games on YouTube to give me ideas for my game's design.

This form uses the verb **analyse** to make the sentence sound better.